# When opening enginesim, a command prompt flashes and goes away

Tags: windows-7, command-line, java

When opening the turbo.class or turbo.java file for enginesim, 
[found here](http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/airplane/javplts/engsim18/applet/EngineSim.zip), the command prompt flashes and then exits. Using the commands `java -cp . turbo.class`, `java -cp . turbo.java`, `java turbo.java`, etc, I get `Error: Could not find or load main class turbo.class`
Also, when just executing `java -cp . Turbo` from the location of the extracted files, I get `Error: Main method not found in class Turbo, please define the main method as:

public static void main (string[]args)

or a javaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application`
Windows 7. administrator.

Comment: Seems to be an applet. Do you have JRE installed? Did you try to open the HTML files in a browser?

Comment: That was stupid of me! Thanks! Needed to open the html file, now I need to get permission to let `file://` be execute in java